# How to find which adjectives modify which nouns?

Tags: word-choice, dictionaries

I've always wanted to to find the answer to such questions as the following:

1. Which adjectives are commonly used to describe *pain*?
2. Which nouns are commonly modified by the adjective *acute*?

You can certainly find the answer if you look into usage examples in the dictionary or if you poke around in a thesaurus, but the answer is not always found directly. I couldn't even find a list of bi-grams that addressed this specific construct.

Similarly, I would like to know which verbs commonly associate with which subjects and which objects and vice versa.

Where do I find such information? And should this not be in a thesaurus?

Comment: Probably better on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try searching for [**collocations**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collocation) + the word you want the adjectives, nouns, or even verbs paired to.

According to [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/) collocations are

> - The *habitual juxtaposition of a particular word with another word* or words with a frequency greater than chance.
>
> ‘the words have a similar range of collocation’
>
> - *A pair or group of words that are habitually juxtaposed*.
>
> ‘‘strong tea’ and ‘heavy drinker’ are typical English collocations’

For example, a search for [**collocations+pain**](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=pain) returned the following (amongst others) from the Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary:

> acute, agonizing, awful, excruciating, extreme, great, intense, severe, sharp, terrible, unbearable | burning, searing, shooting, stabbing, throbbing, etc.

A search for [**collocations+acute**](http://collocations.enacademic.com/187/acute) rendered the following results amongst others:

> ↑agitation, ↑angle, ↑anxiety, ↑appendicitis, ↑asthma, ↑attack, ↑awareness, ↑case, ↑complication, ↑crisis, ↑danger, ↑depression, ↑diarrhoea, ↑dilemma, ↑discomfort, ↑disease, ↑distress, etc.

**Edited to add the following**

Thanks [3omarz](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/115700/3omarz)!

I found two more online collocation dictionary sources which in my opinion will be helpful and more accurate than the previously cited references

[**Flax Interactive Language Learning**](http://flax.nzdl.org/greenstone3/flax?a=g&rt=r&sa=CollocationQuery&s=CollocationQuery&c=collocations&s1.title=&s1.threshold=0.5&s1.startNum=0&s1.sampleNum=10&s1.perPage=20&s1.type=&s1.wordType=&s1.colloType=&s1.query=acute&s1.dbName=Wikipedia)

This online tool appears to be thorough. According to their about section

> "There are many definitions of collocation. We think of collocations in the same way as expressed by Benson et al.: "In any language, certain words combine with certain other words or grammatical constructions. These recurrent, semi-fixed combinations, or collocations, can be divided into two groups: grammatical collocations and lexical collocations."
>
> Enter this collection to search for the company words keep.
>
> ***How words form into collocational patterns will be revealed by looking across***
>
> - **the 100 million-word British National Corpus (BNC) reference corpus**,
> - **the British Academic Written English (BAWE) corpus of 2500 university student writing texts**
> - **the Wikipedia crowd-sourced corpus of three million articles**.**

[**Just The Word**](http://www.just-the-word.com/main.pl?word=pain&mode=combinations) describe themselves as

> a completely new kind of aid to help you with writing English and choosing just the word.

I suggest you click the "[getting started](http://www.just-the-word.com/jtw_questions.html)" and "[more help](http://www.just-the-word.com/help.html)" links to get more out of the resource.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I asked for. Collocations. It's funny that the first linked site (Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary) returns no results for 'acute', and the second link is not a friendly website so I couldn't find collocations for other words on it. Then what I should be asking for is a quality collocations dictionary. We need that for every language. It's as useful as a dictionary, if not more. Thank you.

Comment: The Flax website is perfect. Exactly what I want. And it even provides multiple patterns of collocations even with prepositions in between.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an exhaustive list of words which can be used along with the word "pain". These adjectives can be used depending on the context, the subject, length of the phrase/sentence.

These are words which describe pain in different forms.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/physically-painful-and-describing-pain

Comment: Well. How do you find such information? How did you find that page for instance?! I tried searching "describing pain" but it returned no results. Because it seems that you just proved my point that such information is not directly found.

Comment: Well, finding answers requires a bit of "seeking for" rather than simple searching.